# How to use Drupal in the cloud with on demand instances

Tags: performance

Services such as [Rightscale](http://www.rightscale.com/) do lots of things to help mange unpredictable traffic and bring more servers online when traffic spikes.

**Is it possible to use Drupal with services such as this?**

While Drupal can be set up for a number of configurations, is it possible to set it up so the configuration is flexible.

**What do you need to do to make sure it works?**

Assuming that you can bring on demand instances online, what do you need to do to make sure that Drupal will work in this situation. What do you *have* to do?

**What is the optimal setup?**

Once you have done what you *have to* do, what *should* you do to ensure that you can scale to more servers seamlessly. What is the best configuration in terms of number of servers. How many caching servers should you bring on line for each web server. Should you scale each tier independently?

*edit*

Edit to clarify that this is to do with the implications of *on demand* scaling for a Drupal site.

Comment: this is probably a question better placed on serverfault

Comment: I would disagree, it is very Drupal specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rackspace put together a pretty decent start to this subject [here](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/blog/2010/05/25/deploying-drupal-in-the-cloud-with-nginx-and-boost/) which uses a couple of specific technologies which you might not want to use, but the principles are the same.

You might also need to look at Mysql clustering, but only really if you're hitting serious traffic levels

Comment: I have a webapp at Rackspace in development, and we are planning pretty much what you see in the figure from Ewan's link above. I have just started working on the scaling logic, and the biggest bang for the buck is having a dedicated DB server. We're also looking at Panethon, having had a beta peek: https://getpantheon.com/platform Panethon is a "managed scaling Drupal cloud infrastructure as a service".

Comment: @Ewan, the "here" link is not available anymore.

Answer (score -1):

if the webservice supports php5 and mysql then there should be no problems with running drupal in the cloud. that said you may want to consider looking at the pressflow fork of drupal if you are looking for serious scaling

Comment: Running in the cloud is fine, it is on demand scaling that I am interested in, so adding new servers as demand rises.