# How do I setup Drupal with EC2 scaling?

Tags: 6, files, performance

I want to scale my Drupal site and I was wondering how to approach it with Drupal and Amazon EC2. This is a bit related to [How to use Drupal in the cloud with on demand instances](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224/how-to-use-drupal-in-the-cloud-with-on-demand-instances).

With Amazon, I can monitor my server and if certain metrics are hit then it can launch a new instance that is load-balanced. My questions are then:

- Does Drupal create specific files as users do stuff? Is everything on the database? (I have a separate database server that all my nodes point to.)
- Are sessions local or is it on the database as well? I'm thinking of situations where user connects to server A and then gets moved to server B. Would the user lose anything?

If it helps, I'm using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Drupal core code creates files only when a user uploads a file. With third-party modules, files could be created in other cases. For example, if you are using [Apache Solr Search Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) some files could be created; if you are using a module that implements an alternative caching system, some files could be created as well.
- [sess_write()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--session.inc/function/sess_write/6) saves the session ID in the "{sessions}" table, together the value of `$user->cache`, the IP address used by the user to connect, and the current timestamp.

```
db_query("UPDATE {sessions} SET uid = %d, cache = %d, hostname = '%s', session = '%s', timestamp = %d WHERE sid = '%s'", $user->uid, isset($user->cache) ? $user->cache : '', ip_address(), $value, time(), $key);
if (db_affected_rows()) {
  // Last access time is updated no more frequently than once every 180 seconds.
  // This reduces contention in the users table.
  if ($user->uid && time() - $user->access > variable_get('session_write_interval', 180)) {
    db_query("UPDATE {users} SET access = %d WHERE uid = %d", time(), $user->uid);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2018, [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/drupal/cloud) is a good option for installing Drupal 8 on AWS EC2 with Debian Linux & a LAMP stack with all of the required components. Use Drush & Composer to manage the CMS, Git for version control. It is required to use [AWS RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hadrupal-tutorial.html) with [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-drupal-website/) as the load balancer for the database synchronization when using MySQL or MariaDB in cluster server configurations.